# Problem with invoking a function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, addresses, address.transfer

I have a function as follows i.e. `transfer`.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 ENvalue, uint256 PWvalue) public returns (bool) {
require(_to != address(0));

balances[_to].bEN = balances[_to].bEN + ENvalue;

balances[_to].bPW = balances[_to].bPW + PWvalue;

return true;
```

}

When I invoke this function as follows:

```
    contractInstance.methods.transfer('0x31c5f6A1fDb0C142742478eb31B710E9D47eAEe9', 5, 10).send({ from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773' }, function(error, result) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(result)
});
```

I receive following message:

```
> contractInstance.methods.transfer('0x31c5f6A1fDb0C142742478eb31B710E9D47eAEe9', 5, 10).send({ from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773' }, function(error, result) {
...     console.log(error);
...     console.log(result)
... });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: undefined,
  emit: [Function: emit],
  on: [Function: on],
  once: [Function: once],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  listeners: [Function: listeners],
  addListener: [Function: on],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners] }
```

and when I get the balance of `0x31c5f6A1fDb0C142742478eb31B710E9D47eAEe9` it is still **zero**. Is there something wrong ?

```
> contractInstance.methods.balanceOfPW('0x31c5f6A1fDb0C142742478eb31B710E9D47eAEe9').call({ from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773' }, function(error, result) {
...     console.log(error);
...     console.log(result)
... });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> null
0
```

And for getting balances :

```
struct Balances {
    uint256 bEN;
    uint256 bPW;
  }
  mapping(address => Balances) balances;
function balanceOfEN(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner].bEN;
  }
  function balanceOfPW(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner].bPW;
  }
```

Comment: can you show the code for balanceOfPW?

Comment: @shaish I added in question.

Comment: tested in remix, it works. are you sure you gave the original transaction time to get mined?

Comment: @shaish I don't know how long is enough to be sure a transaction is mined ?

Comment: you have callbacks that get called in this case (or you can split the function in two, look in etherscan, and then run the second function,or if you're running locally on ganache just wait for the promise to resolve).

Comment: @shaish Thank you, Does it depend on "gas" value that I used at time of deploying contract ? I mean if i change gas value something is changed here or not ?

Comment: no if the contract is already deployed it doesn't affect anything the amount of gas you used when deploying it

Comment: @shaish When I test my contract with remix it's ok, however when with parity i connect to network (i.e. https://energyweb.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EWF/pages/72974337/How+to+get+startet+with+Tobalaba) after "one day" its balance is still zero. Is it normal? I can also bring here entire my contract code.

Comment: @shaish I also ask onother question here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47237/how-to-get-transaction-hash-at-time-of-invoking-function I thank you if you could guide me about it.