# How to get transaction hash at time of invoking function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, parity, contract-invocation

I have a function as follows:

```
function setEnergy(address dev, uint256 energy) public returns (bool) {
    require(dev != address(0));

    amount[dev].energyValue = amount[dev].energyValue + energy;
    energyTotalSupply = energyTotalSupply + energy;

    emit setEnergyEvent(dev, energy);

    return true;
  }
```

And I invok it as follows to get its transaction hash:

```
contractInstance.methods.setEnergy('0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773', 10).send({ from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773' }, function(error, result, transactionHash) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(transactionHash);
    console.log(result)
});
```

This is the output I get:

```
> contractInstance.methods.setEnergy('0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773', 10).send({ from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773' }, function(error, result, transactionHash) {
...     console.log(error);
...     console.log(transactionHash);
...     console.log(result)
... });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: undefined,
  emit: [Function: emit],
  on: [Function: on],
  once: [Function: once],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  listeners: [Function: listeners],
  addListener: [Function: on],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners] }
```

I deployed this contract as follows :

```
var thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, {
    from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773',
    gasPrice: '20000000000'
});

//GAS ESTIMATE
thisContract.deploy({ data: bytecode }).estimateGas(function(err, gas) { console.log(gas); });

thisContract.deploy({ data: bytecode }).send({
        from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773',
        gas: 3000000,
        gasPrice: '3000000000'
    },
    function(error, transactionHash) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(transactionHash);
        console.log('function exec');
    }).then(function(newContractInstance) {
    console.log('Contract Instance:' + newContractInstance.options.address);
});
```

**What is the reason I do not get any result including transaction hash after one day ?**

P.S.1 I tested it with remix and it works.

P.S.2 This contract is deployed on Tobalaba blockchain : https://energyweb.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EWF/pages/72974337/How+to+get+startet+with+Tobalaba

Comment: Are you using mainnet or a testnet? The common causes for transaction delays are not enough funds or gas price too low.

Comment: @Ismael Do you mean "gas price" at time of deploying contract?

Comment: @Ismael I updated my question. If you need any other information, please let me know. thanks